# Devise two separate sign up forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I want to create a separate sign up form for a devise user.  This form should have its own controller as the logic for this form will be significantly different.  How would I go about doing this?

For example, I currently have a users/registrations/new.html.erb page, how would I go about creating a users/registrations/promo.html.erb page? What would the new controller and route look like?

Answer (score 1):

You would have to write your own custom controller for device. Below are the routes which could get you started. In the controller you could now write the registration logic as per your requirements.

**Routes**

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => "registrations" }, :path => "users", :path_names => {:sign_up => "register"}
devise_scope :user do
    post "/users/promo" =>"registrations#promo"
end
```

**Registration Controller**

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def create
    #Code for '/users' route to be here
  end

  def promo
    #Code for '/users/promo' route to be here
  end

end
```

Comment: Thanks.  The only thing is that when I try to visit the users/promo page, I get the following error:                                           'No route matches [GET] "/users/promo"'   It only works if I change the route to:                                                                  'get "/users/promo" => "registrations#promo"'                                       Do I then need a separate route for the post action?

Comment: Well you could have another route for the get method on `/users/promo`. Though I would recommend that the action where user object is created be a post method. It depends upon you how you manage the routes.

Comment: Works for me. Thanks.